# Dynamically find the optimal number of Actors

Tags: java, scala, akka

I have a master actor which processes messages by delegating them to its children and I want to find the optimal number of children that will process these messages the quickest. The number of children should change with time as the load on the server changes from other applications demanding resources. Are there some Routers or patterns to do this that are already popular?

**Edit:** I have very specific needs to do this, each actor is responsible for taking care of a process it starts which does all the computationally intensive work, so the actors themselves are not doing any real work, they are there solely for concurrency. This is not a question so much as to optimizing akka itself, or code on the jvm, but rather how many instances of an application to run in parallel for the best performance. This is entirely dependent on how many workers there are. If there are more processors than available cores then I start to see a massive decrease in performance, which happens when other users start using the server my application is running on. Normally I wouldn't care about this sort of optimization, but the app is running a large number of simulations, which can take days, potentially months. This problem is extremely important in the field I work in (Engineering) where simulations can take forever. Normally you wouldn't be competing for resources like this but this is the situation in, which I have no control over.

Please understand that none of the following is useful to me.

- Suggestions to dedicate the server to my app only - I am not able to do this.
- To throttle messages - The Processes themselves hog CPUs when idle, starting and killing them takes allot of cpu as well because they are connecting to other servers via tcp

For the bounty answers must address how to naively control the number of actors in some manor which responds to the time to process the messages. The messages are always the same amount of work, so this is not a horrible strategy, though not the best but like I said, any small optimization is worth if for my case, whilst I understand in general this is not a great approach.

Comment: akka's built-in dispatchers allows to set minimum and maximum number of threads to be used. The type of dispatcher decides which strategy should be used to increase or decrease the amount of active threads. So you should only specify the bounds.

Comment: You don't have enough information here to get an answer. A real solution would require fairly deep understanding of the apps, their schedule, how much I/O they do, and various other details. You will get better performance if a process can run uninterrupted on a core, as their data will more often remain in CPU cache -- but you have no way to gauge when a core is free, and even if you could, you likely couldnt react fast enough to take advantage of it.

Comment: I suggest looking at Mesos/Marathon or Yarn -- or even running your apps in docker containers. You need to control your resources.

Comment: @Rich Henry Yarn looks cool, I don't have the time to redo what I've done however, maybe in the future if I do something like this again I will use it.  Seems like people don't like this question but it's my reality.

Comment: You can still run the apps in linux containers (assuming linux use) without modification. Then you can restrict the resource use of the containers to stop the apps from running each other over.

Comment: I did pass the applications command line arguments to use single processor/core, but would you say the linux container will ensure with 100% certainty this will be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using https://github.com/iheartradio/kanaloa
A set of work dispatchers implemented using Akka actors with auto scaling, back pressure, circuit breaker and realtime monitor.

Answer (score 1):

First, blocking an actor is strongly not recommended (as you can read in [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html#Blocking_Needs_Careful_Management)) - you can always delegate blocking operation to the `Future` executing inside separate `ForkJoinPool`, but best is to use async APIs (and [reactive](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/)-complient solutions) of course. If your blocking is [managed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/XIhVwRZiucE) (simply saying, wrapped with `scala.concurrent.blocking`) FJ-Pool is gonna adapt to the load automatically, and use maximum of CPU (see below how to control this maximum); however, creating a compensation thread may cost you a lot. So still, it's better to be "reactive" than using FJs.

So what's left after that is to choose correct size of your pool. Usually, people just set it to be equal to number of processors, so resposibilty for allocating CPU time goes to the JVM+OS. However, JVM allows you to measure system business to adjust, see [OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html), [ThreadMXBean](http://kickjava.com/src/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.java.htm).

So you can have count of workers equals to the count of processors, but when OS is too busy you can just ignore some of them. It's a pretty normal practice as it's never good to have count of active workers (at the moment) more than number of processors.

So using that idea you can create some kind of back-pressure on your system. See [Akka and BackPressure](http://blog.abhinav.ca/blog/2014/01/13/akka-and-backpressure/) and [Throttling](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/throttle.html) for Akka. The key difference between back-pressure and throttling is that back-pressure is going notify outer systems that you are busy - you don't have to store messages inside your buffer, so you can control memory consumption as well.

Talking about how exactly to choose (precisely saying, dynamically reduce them from the maximum) values based on current stats -  [Queuing Theory](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-Thread-Pool-Performance-Tuning) may help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you pay much of a penalty for an `Actor` with an empty mailbox, so there is no real need to scale down the actor count.

If you accept this, then any of the basic routers for worker pools will work for you, with some upper limit based on the number of cores/threads you want this actor to have active at a given time, i.e.:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#SmallestMailboxPool

An alternative approach might be to create an actor to handle each incoming task that will terminate after handling the input. To do this you just create the actor in the handler for the incoming message, and have that actor stop itself after completing its work and providing results.

Any optimization beyond these strategies should only come after you've tried these and found them insufficient -- don't prematurely optimize.